# Force logout user laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a little confuse on how to solve this problem,

> Assuming a user login on the date of 2016-06-16, so if the date is
>   2016-06-17 the user will be forced logout.

I am using laravel framework. I used carbon for capturing the date of the login.

Answer (score 2):

As Per [Laravel Discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/session-time-out-n-laravel-51) :

> In File `config/session.php` :
>
> Change Line :
>
> ```
> 'lifetime' => 120,
> ```